# Sqlite insert values not Working

Tags: java, android, html

Hi I have an issue with database SQLite android.

please check my code for reference

when I am going to insert values it returns -1 that I come to know from debug which is not inserting values so tell me what is wrong

here is my create table method:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(
                "create table user_table " +
                        "(id integer primary key, name text,phone text,question text)"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_table");
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

Here is the insert method:

```
public int insertContact (String name, String phone, String question) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("name", name);
        contentValues.put("phone", phone);
        contentValues.put("question", question);
        Long result = db.insert("contacts", null, contentValues);
        if(result == -1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
            return 2;
    }
```

this is from where i am calling the method:

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               int s =  mydb.insertContact(name.getText().toString(),phone.getText().toString(),question.getText().toString());
               if(s ==1)
               {
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
               else
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

Comment: You are creating a `user_table` table, but attempting to insert in a `contacts` table .

Comment: `Long result = db.insert("contacts", null, contentValues);` inserting data in wrong table. change this 
`Long result = db.insert("user_table ", null, contentValues);`

Comment: that is just my method name. it won't make any difference right @Berger

Comment: @tencho welcome!!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a table named  `user_table`, but enter values into a table named `contacts` which is actually not exists.

Change this line

```
  Long result = db.insert("contacts", null, contentValues);
```

to,

```
 Long result = db.insert("user_table ", null, contentValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to give same name to table when you create and insert data to it.**

Please change it

```
  "create table user_table " +
                        "(id integer primary key, name text,phone text,question text)"
```

to

```
 "create table contacts " +
                        "(id integer primary key, name text,phone text,question text)"
```

**or if you want to add data in user_table then change**

```
Long result = db.insert("user_table", null, contentValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

change your `insertContact` method with below:

```
public int insertContact (String name, String phone, String question) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put("name", name);
            contentValues.put("phone", phone);
            contentValues.put("question", question);
            Long result = db.insert("user_table", null, contentValues);
            if(result == -1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
                return 2;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your table name

```
        Long result = db.insert("user_table", null, contentValues);
```